# Prevent overlapping labels and images in D3 7.8.5 plot

Tags: d3.js

i have a scatter plot with images as data points. Each point has a description label. My problem is that labels overlap other labels and images:
[image: overlapping]

I want that the labels are not overlapping other labels and ideally are not overlap with the images. The label position can be around the image. It's not necessary to be above. If no free space for the label is available the label should be hidden.

I found this jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/qrpr0wre/), but it's not compatible with version 7.8.5 and i found some examples which uses `d3.forceSimulation` but i'm not sure this is the correct way for my requirement.

i'm using svg text an image tags to draw the items:

```js
            const width = 1300;
            const height = 800;
            const padding = { top: 10, bottom: 50, left: 20, right: 50 };

            // X/Y Scale
            var xScale = d3.scaleSymlog()
                .domain([0, 110])
                .range([0, width]);
            var yScale = d3.scaleSymlog()
                .domain([-50, 1000])
                .range([height, 0]);

            // append the svg object to the body of the page
            var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("id", "chartSvg")
                .attr("width", width + padding.left + padding.right)
                .attr("height", height + padding.top + padding.bottom);

            var plotArea = svg.append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + [padding.left, padding.top] + ")")
                .attr("id", "plotArea");


            var panableContent = plotArea.append('g')
                .attr('id', 'panableContent');

            var logosAndText = panableContent.selectAll("g")
                .data(jsonData.Items)
                .enter()
                .append("g");

            var logos = logosAndText.append("image")
                .attr("width", 32)
                .attr("height", 32)
                .attr("x", (d) => { return xScale(d.XValue) - (32 / 2) })
                .attr("y", function (d) { return yScale(d.YValue) - (32 / 2); })
                .attr("href", function (d) {                 
                    return "https://d3js.org/logo.svg"; 
                });


            var texts = logosAndText.append("text")
                .attr("x", function (d) { return xScale(d.XValue) - (32 / 2); })
                .attr("y", function (d) { return yScale(d.YValue) - (32 / 2); })
                .text((d) => { return "Dies ist ein Text"; });
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I'm completely happy with my algorithm but since I worked it up I figured I post.   This is a niave brute-force algorithm that attempts to place the labels around the image until it finds a position of no overlapping.  If if fails to find a position it hides the label:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="my_dataviz"></div>
    <script>
      const width = 500;
      const height = 500;
      const padding = { top: 50, bottom: 50, left: 10, right: 20 };

      var jsonData = {};
      jsonData.Items = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        jsonData.Items.push({
          XValue: 110 * Math.random(),
          YValue: 1000 * Math.random(),
        });
      }

      // X/Y Scale
      var xScale = d3.scaleSymlog().domain([0, 110]).range([0, width]);
      var yScale = d3.scaleSymlog().domain([0, 1000]).range([height, 0]);

      // append the svg object to the body of the page
      var svg = d3
        .select('#my_dataviz')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('id', 'chartSvg')
        .attr('width', width + padding.left + padding.right)
        .attr('height', height + padding.top + padding.bottom);

      var plotArea = svg
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + [padding.left, padding.top] + ')')
        .attr('id', 'plotArea');

      var panableContent = plotArea.append('g').attr('id', 'panableContent');

      var logosAndText = panableContent
        .selectAll('g')
        .data(jsonData.Items)
        .enter()
        .append('g');

      var logos = logosAndText
        .append('image')
        .attr('width', 32)
        .attr('height', 32)
        .attr('x', (d) => {
          return xScale(d.XValue) - 32 / 2;
        })
        .attr('y', function (d) {
          return yScale(d.YValue) - 32 / 2;
        })
        .attr('href', function (d) {
          return 'https://d3js.org/logo.svg';
        });

      var texts = logosAndText
        .append('text')
        .attr('x', function (d) {
          return xScale(d.XValue) - 32 / 2;
        })
        .attr('y', function (d) {
          return yScale(d.YValue) - 32 / 2;
        })
        .text((d) => {
          return 'Dies ist ein Text';
        });

      // given two svg elements determine if they overlap
      let isOverlap = (src, targ) => {
        let srcBBox = src.getBBox(),
          targBBox = targ.getBBox();
        return (
          srcBBox.x + srcBBox.width >= targBBox.x &&
          targBBox.x + targBBox.width >= srcBBox.x &&
          srcBBox.y + srcBBox.height >= targBBox.y &&
          targBBox.y + targBBox.height >= srcBBox.y
        );
      };

      // given an element determine if it overlaps anyone else
      let isOverlapAny = (src) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < allNodesLength; i++) {
          let targ = allNodes[i];
          if (src === targ) continue;
          if (src.parentNode === targ.parentNode) continue;
          if (isOverlap(src, targ)) return true;
        }
        return false;
      };

      // 6 possible placements of label relative to image
      let adjustPlacement = (src, i) => {
        let t = d3.select(src);
        switch (i) {
          case 0:
            t.style('display', 'block');            
            t.attr('y', src.previousSibling.getBBox().y);
            t.attr('text-anchor', 'start')
            return true;
          case 1:
            t.attr('text-anchor', 'middle');
            return true;
          case 2:
            t.attr('text-anchor', 'end');
            return true;
          case 3:
            t.attr('y', src.previousSibling.getBBox().y + 40);
            t.attr('text-anchor', 'start');
            return true;
          case 4:
            t.attr('text-anchor', 'middle');
            return true;
          case 5:
            t.attr('text-anchor', 'end');
            return true;
          case 6:
            t.style('display', 'none');
            return false;
        }
      };

      // store off some consts for faster computation
      const textNodes = texts.nodes(),
        allNodes = texts.nodes().concat(logos.nodes());
        allNodesLength = allNodes.length;

      setTimeout( () => {
        // run two iterations of placement checking
        // this way as other labels move we can double-check
        // those that were overlapped on their first pass
        for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
          textNodes.forEach((src) => {
            let c = 0;    
            while (isOverlapAny(src) && (adjustPlacement(src, c))) {
              c += 1;
            }
          });
        }
      },1000);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```